# Android x86- GRUB Loader Error 17

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, grub, grub2, android-x86

Let see if this is the right place...

I installed and have ran Android -x86 on a virtual machine. Everything works great until I have to force dismount the ISO file from the machine, so that it can load from the partition. Whenever I do this, I get the error GRUB Loader Error 17 or 15. It depends. I formatted the partition to ext4, mainly because it doesnt allow me to format in ext3.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again!

Comment: Can try this answer http://superuser.com/questions/1052597/android-x86-6-0-marshmallow-in-virtualboxinstallation-stuck-on-grub?rq=1

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the error! Thank you! Thank you!